# what are the different ways of spring bean configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**Background:**

We have spring context configuration for tests. For tests(component) we use cucumber features. For executing these tests we created MockDispatcherServlet.Inside this, we read properties file.

Also we defined some highlevel(reusable) classes which will be used while defining step definitions of cucumber feature.

I observed these highlevel classes are not annotated with @Component or @Service...etc and even they didn't have any manual bean definition in the cucumber.xml(which is where we are scanning the these classes packages).

**Problem:**
We are only scanning these classes packages. As far as I know to initialize a bean we need to either annotate with @Component or @Service...etc or we need to define that bean manually. Without these two approaches, how a spring container is able to initialize those highlevel classes?

Comment: Could be done programmatically. Simeting like ApplicationContext context; context.addBean(bean)

Comment: @sashok_bg,It could be done that way but in our project we didn't do that. So i am unable to understand how its working

Comment: If you're unable to understand it with the whole code available, and with your colleagues having confifured and set up everything, how could we without any single line of code available?

Comment: @JB nizet, Its the old implementation and no one is in the current team who did it. Let me know where you are not clear so that I can add more details